# uninstalling pycharm in MacBook

Tags: pycharm

I use pycharm on my MacBook for few month. I want to uninstall it .
how can I do this?
when I do routine uninstalling in my Mac, it does not work and still there is pycharm on my mack book and it is not installed yet

uninstalling pycharm on mac